# How to get total count of fields under multiple columns in the same table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table in which I have columns as (Id, Fname, Lname, Age, PNR_NO). The Age column contains the age of children only and for others, it is a null and to differentiate b/w Adults and Childs we put prefix as "Chd." in the Fname column for Child entries which is coming from my front-end application.

Now I need to get the total counts of Adults as AdultNum, total counts of Childs as ChildNum, Age1, Age2. I am requiring these in this way because I need to store them in this order in my DataTable in C# file for some calculation to get the rates.

I have tried the below code but it gives the total count of one column only.

```
SELECT count(*) AS ChildNum FROM hc_data WHERE Fname LIKE'Chd_%' and 
PNRNO = '18717162620'
```

please help me to achieve the desired result.
Your support will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Your query is a bit out of the blue as compared to the question you asked.  You should add sample data and output which explains what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you wanted ?

use CASE statement on Fname to differentiate Child from Adult

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Fname LIKE 'Chd_%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ChildNum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Fname NOT LIKE 'Chd_%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AdultNum 
FROM   hc_data
```

Comment: Great help sir but this helped me to achieve half of the result. I also need Age1 and Age 2. But thanks for the help.

Comment: you can do it similar to the query i posted. Please do try, if it doesn't work, post your query

Comment: Sure sir... Thanks once again.